# Ввод данных в ячейку PHP и mySql

Tags: php

К примеру, у меня есть таблица 15х20. Где 1 столбец - это имена, а верхняя строка - это дата. Как мне ввести данное на пересечении имени на 3 строке и дате в 5 столбце. Как это осуществить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле, как придумаете хранение, так и придется реализовывать. Можно иметь таблицу фамилий и таблицу с датами отдельно. Каждая строка - это отдельная дата. А далее можно просто в ячейке писать IDчеловека::оценка\n и по \n потом разбирать по строкам. Рядом можно иметь такое же, но с отметками присутствия и так далее. Вариантов на самом деле много. Кто какой придумает, такой и сделает.

Второй вариант. Таблица людей, а в другой таблице сделать ячейки - дата, оценка, ИД человека и заносить в них просто по порядку, кому ставите его ИД, дату и оценку.